# IONIC STATE RESTORE no longer works

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to restore my project plugins and bundle identifier,
but this command doesn't work anymore:

```
ionic state restore
```

Whats the new command?

Answer (score 0):

The new command is

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

**in case you haven't noticed now you have to put

```
ionic cordova
```

in front of all commands now... except for

```
ionic serve
```

that one still works :D